# Django - Post list not appearing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Django blog posts not appearing

I am new to Django and am trying to return a list of published blog posts.

The page is appearing and no errors are produced, however no posts are showing. I have checked in the admin page and all posts are published.

Model:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    snippet = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True)
    Blog_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_pics',blank=True)
    hero_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_pics',blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    blogcategory = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='uncategorised')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    #def publish(self):
    #    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    #    self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("BlogPost_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Views:

```
class BlogPostListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BlogPost.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')

class BlogPostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = BlogPost
```

Template:

```
{% for BlogPost in BlogPost_list %}

          <div class="col-sm-6">
               <a href="{% url 'BlogPost_detail' pk=BlogPost.pk %}">
                 <div class="card">
                 <img src="#">
                   <div class="">
                       <h4><span class="">{{ BlogPost.category }}</span></h4>
                       <p class="">{{ BlogPost.tile }}</p>
                       <p class="">{{ BlogPost.snippet }}</p>
                        <p style="">{{ BlogPost.published_date }</p>
                        <p style="">x min</p>
                   </div>
               </div>
             </a>
           </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ListView store a list inside `object_list` in the context so try `for BlogPost in object_list` instead

Comment: Thanks - that solved it!!